SenderID Mismatch
Im trying to use the new api of fcm, but it keeps telling me that the sender id is not the same as the one in fcm console
Im using this code
public function notif(Request $req)
{
    try
    {            
        $device_id = "DEVICE_ID";            
        $fcmEndpoint = 'fcm_endpoint';            
        $client = new Client();

        $token = $this->getAuthToken();

        // Send a POST request to the FCM endpoint
        $response = $client->post($fcmEndpoint, [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            ],
            'json' => [
                "message"=> [
                    'token' => "$device_id",
                    'notification' => [
                        'title' => "Test Tite",
                        'body' => "This is a test notification",
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        
        $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
        
        $responseBody = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        if ($statusCode == 200) {
           
            return $responseBody;
        } else {
            
            return "Failed to send message. Status code: $statusCode, Response: $responseBody";
        }
    }catch(Throwable $e)
    {
        Log::error($e);
        return response()->json([
            'errors' => $e->getMessage(),
            'message' => __('fails.errors.500')
        ], 500, [], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }               
}

public function getAuthToken()
{
    $keyFilePath = 'SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE';
    
    if (!File::exists($keyFilePath)) {        
        return 'JSON key file not found';        
    }

    $credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging',
        $keyFilePath
    );

    $accessToken = $credentials->fetchAuthToken()['access_token'];
    
    return $accessToken;
}

it returns this

Client error: POST https:\/\/fcm.googleapis.com\/v1\/projects\/attendance-monitoring-13ba6\/messages:send resulted in a 403 Forbidden response:\n{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "SenderId mismatch",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n    "details": [\n (truncated...)\n


Try to remove " like this 'token' => $device_id
